# Create Regex pattern for calculator

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a calculator,where operands are words.It can repeat any number of times.
    e.g. EmpName+xyz  or  EmpName   or x+rr+fff.
    It should reject such pattern e.g.
    EmpName+
    I created a regular expression:

```
 (?m)(?<Operand>^[a-z].*?)(?<Operator>[+*])  

On this output:  
  1) a + b  
  2) ab+dddd  
  3) ab*fffff*ggggg  
  4) dfg+fg4444+fgf4  
  5) xxxxx  
But it only targets 1,2,3,4 and up to only first operator. Output in regex 2.05. 
"Operand: [ab]"  
"Operator:[+]"  
I am using regex builder 2.05 to test my regex.  How i can repeat this pattern any number of times?  Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Do you need to cover parentheses as well?

Comment: Which language are you working with?

Comment: Yes i need parantheses as well as divide,percentage,minus sign also. I am working in .net

Comment: Use regular expressions for recognizing words, not structures. http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html

Comment: @Kore : My words are not fixed.So i cant directly put words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would typically be expressed as

- *operand* followed by (*operator*  *operand*) one or more times

that is

- `(?m)<Operand>([+*]<Operator>)*`

---

> *Yes i need parantheses as well as divide,percentage,minus sign also.*

Then I suggest considering using a real parser. The language of balanced parentheses is not regular.

Comment: +1 for your logic.You are absolutely right.But as i am new in regular expression so i am not able to convert this logic into regex.Please help me.

Comment: I wrote a regex:  (?im)(?<Operand>\w+)(?<Operator>[+*])(?<ndOperand>\w+)    But groups correctly,but not repeat.If i use * at last,then it gives invalid group.And it is not picking if i only give one operand.Am i going in a wrong direction ?